# How can I customise my Ubuntu login page for 15.10?

Tags: login-screen

I had installed Ubuntu formatting my Windows. I need my login screen look beautiful instead of default screen. How can I get it?

Comment: Can we see the default, and can we see what you want? Take photos, upload to imgur.com

Comment: I need to change my login screen. It shows the same desktop wallpaper as login wallpaper and also the position of password input field should be changed.  How can I do it?

Comment: So you want a different wall paper and a different position?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45315/how-to-change-the-ubuntu-linux-login-screen/

Comment: It doesn't work here. Sorry. Can you suggest me something else for that?

Comment: @SherK, Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. that needs a modification of the source code, it's vala language. package name: `unity-greeter` . Do you have any programming experience?

Comment: @Sneetsher I would be interested in it. Could you point me to related files and/or methods. New to Vala though.

Comment: @AshharHasan , I found it long for comment, so i posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

That needs a modification of the source code

1. Download source and build dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep unity-greeter
   apt-get source unity-greeter
   cd unity-greeter-*/
   ```
2. Images in `data/` folder, source code `src/` in Vala language (similar to C syntax)
3. Build

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   ./configure
   make -j2
   ```
4. Install

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```
5. Restart lightdm service (WARNING: it will kill you current session)

   ```
   sudo service lightdm restart
   ```

Note: There should be another easier way using tests/ files for testing it without lightdm restart. But i didn't look much for it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. le me try it and share the result with you.